# ReferenceError: modelName is not defined - error while trying to access objects through mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a project web app that is meant to be used for organizing an art collection. I had no problems connecting my js with mongoose. However, the mongo shell doesn't recognize the name of my model. I don't really know what I'm not getting.

Here's the code:

models/artPiece.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const artPieceSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    artist: String,
    technique: String,
    year: Number,
    size_x: Number,
    size_y: Number,
    owner: String,
    holder: String,
    acquiration_date: Date, // if updated, have to notiy mongoose with 'doc.markModified('pathToYourDate')' -- check the docs if in doubt
    archival: Boolean,
    description: String,
},
{
    timestamps: true, 

}
);

const ArtPiece = mongoose.model('ArtPiece', artPieceSchema, 'artpieces');
module.exports = ArtPiece;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejsMate = require ('ejs-mate');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/artCollection',
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
    console.log('connection open!')
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('oh no!')
    console.log(err)
});

const ArtPiece = require('./models/artPiece.js');


app.get('/makeArtPiece', async (req, res) => {
    const piece = new ArtPiece({
        title: 'Scream',
        artist: 'Munch' })
   
    await piece.save(); 
    res.send(piece)
    })

app.get('/collection', (req, res) => {
    res.render('collection')
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000!')
});
```

[The test objects were successfully added to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLxp3.png)

[But now I cannot access them through the mongo shell using the name of my Model even though I think I'm supposed to be able to do so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS73h.png)

Could somebody maybe, please, show me what I'm missing here.
Thanks.

Comment: Your models have no context in the mongosh shell so you can't use them. Mongoose is a Node package. Mongosh is a shell. You would have to define/import the file where your Models are defined. I'm not even sure this can be done in the shell.

Comment: Ok, so my misunderstanding must've been due to an error in my notes. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to require the models within the shell?

Comment: You can import your Models into the mongosh shell but must use the CommonJS [require function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/require-external-modules/) to do so. Would be interesting to know how you get on using the Models in the mongosh shell...

Comment: Honestly, after trying different solutions for a lot of time, I gave up on using the model in the shell. I just managed the things I wanted to manage by using collection methods, which is what I think I was supposed to do from the beginning. Thanks for clearing out some of the confusion.